# Cors policies are not being applied on dotnet server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

The cors that I configured in dotnet is allowing connections from any domain even though I configure the policies and pass the domain of my web app, how can I fix this? I checked the microsoft documentation and it's exactly like this, I'm using dotnet 7.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IHM46WebDbContext>(options =>
{
    var connectionString = "";
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
});
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TITLE", Version = "v1" });
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CORS",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader();
            });
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("CORS");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Did you miss the two slashes (`//`) from `http:example.com`?

Comment: No, the string shown in the code I placed is an example, in my code my domain is correct.

Comment: I don't think `"http:example.com"` is a valid origin value. Where did you get this from? The [example I found has the slashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware).

Comment: You don't understand, the origin placed in the code is just for example, it is not my real domain, this code is just an example of how my cors is configured, it is not the real code of my project.

Comment: Have you tried moving `app.UseCors("CORS")` higher up so it gets called first before any handler?

Comment: If you try to use `AllowAnyOrigin()`, Can it be success?